# mutt SSL unknown protocol - not able to connect

Tags: arch-linux, openssl, mutt, ssl, imap

I am facing following situation.

1. I am using arch linux
2. I installed mutt the email client
3. I followed the simple guidelines in the arch wiki to configure mutt to use imap
4. For the simple config where no ssl is used, mutt tries to connect via username/password, after entering the password it says
   `Logging in....Login failed` without any error message
5. So i tried to configure mutt to use ssl and ended up with this configuration

   `set ssl_use_sslv3 = yes
    set spoolfile  = imaps://username@domain.de:993
    set folder     = imaps://username@domain.de:993/INBOX
    set mail_check = 10`

Which ends up with the following error:

`SSL failed: error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol`

On the other hand I am establish a connection via openssl to the imap server

`openssl s_client -connect domain.de:993 -quiet`

The endpoint server is a Lotus Domino if this matters.

So I am kind of clueless about those errors.

## Update:

The link posted by @zelldon helped me in that way that setting `ssl_use_sslv3` pushed me several steps forward. But now I got stuck at point 4 again -.-

Comment: http://mutt.sourceforge.net/imap/README.SSL

Comment: What I'd do is to either 1) enable debug logging in mutt (`mutt -d 2 ...`) and find the reason for failing login from ~/.muttdebug0 (see `man mutt` for more info), or (if that fails since mutt was not compiled with debug logging) 2) revert mutt config back to non-SSL IMAP and use Wireshark to capture the dialogue between the server and the client and look for the server response to login. Or, if you have a nice Domino admin, maybe you could ask if there's something in the Domino log that reveals the reason for the error...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same **error issue**

`SSL failed: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol`

but all the hints here didn't help me. For me, it was just to change the port to the right one:

**False**: `set smtp_url = "smtps://user@gmail.com@imap.gmail.com:587/"`

**Right**: `set smtp_url = "smtps://user@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:465/"`

Maybe it's the solution for someone else out there. *Enjoy mutt!*

Comment: By the way: It was _@Earsplit_ who helped me: [ubuntuforums.org](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946910&p=11793704#post11793704)

Answer (score 1):

Well it turned out that the username was incorrect. I was not supposed to use the email-address username but rather then I had to use my internal name instead. So this fixed the problem. Kind of embarrasing :D

Comment: It's good that you shared your experience.